# Unable to get all the sub-menu's in the data compare

Tags: routes, navigation

I am trying to add a rule for comment view for which under the actions I click on data compare.As per the [tutorial](https://drupalize.me/videos/data-types-and-data-selection?p=1157), I have to click the drop down list and choose node.
[image: Data selector with options in the drop down like site,site...,node,view]

Whereas when I repeat the exact same steps from the *Conditions->data* compare I got some lesser menu option :

[image: the data selector has only 4 options site,site..,comment,comment..]

Now my problem is that as I don't have the node option to choose how am I supposed to complete the tutorial.

This kind of missing options appear quite frequently (when I tried to add an action/replacement patterns/ I had to choose the node type whereas in the options list there was no `[node:type]`. Again after 24 hours when I re-try this I get the `[node:type]`)

I don't get the reason which is causing this problem. After doing the troubleshooting steps like re-login, clear browser cache, flush cache the options list is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary way around I have done the reinstall of 7.34 and installed all the modules from the start.This got me back the menu but I cannot do the un-install every time this problem comes.
I will be losing a lot of time